# Unable to see images built through docker remote api's in docker cli result

Tags: docker

Docker remote api v1.6.:

I am using it to POST and build dockerfile. I can see my newly built images in the json image list output by same remote api, http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/api/docker_remote_api_v1.6/#id20 . During build i'm also tagging it with repository name, http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/api/docker_remote_api_v1.6/#id30.
To push this so generated image on the registry am using docker cli. But the reply from docker cli says

> "No such id...".

Since am using docker cli to pull images as well i can't pull it as well.

Please help solving this sync issue in reflecting changes make through docker remote api's into docker cli result?

Comment: I can see it through docker cli only after killing docker processes which force it to restart using different PID.